# Combining get-aduser and get-qadmemberof

Tags: powershell

I am trying to combine these two entries...
get-aduser XXXX | select name,givenname,surname
and
get-qadmemberof -identity XXXX | select name | sort name
they both work fine but I want to combine so my results will show the user's name and below that the groups that the user is in.

Comment: why do you want to do that? `get-aduser XXXX -Properties memberof`

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Aduser XXXX | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | select name
```

This is how to get group names for "XXXX" with Microsoft Native AD module.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways this can be achieved.

**Way 1:**

```
#Output will resemble "CN=GroupName,OU=Groups,OU=Domain,OU=Local" Not always ideal output
Get-ADUser -Identity "TestUser" -Properties -ExpandProperty MemberOf
```

**Way 2: As Kevin Mentioned**

```
#Output will resemble more what you are looking for
Get-ADUser -Identity "TestUser" | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Select-Obeject -ExpandProperty Name
```

**Way 3: Full Script**

```
#This will create a csv titled with the Users sAMAccountName from the .txt file, 
#within that csv is a list of the users groups.
#To improve on this script you could use PSObjects to make this more efficent
#Don't Want to give you all the answers ;)

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$UserList = Get-Content C:\Temp\UserList.txt
ForEach($User in $UserList){
  $UserMembership = Get-ADUser $User | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | Select-Object -Property Name
  $UserMembership | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\$User.CSV" -NoTypeInformation
}
```